# How to increment by a specific number in Select Statement?

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to increment in select statement by a specific number. I understand this one:-

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY SomeColumn ) AS 'rownumber',*
FROM YourTable
```

but I need something like following statement. But coming from c#, I am just trying to show what i need from tsql:-

```
SELECT 
    xValue,
    @x = @x + 0.009 as yValue
FROM
    Table
WHERE
    ID = 1
```

Assume this statement returns 10 rows. Please help.

Comment: Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Since you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT TOP 10 name
             ,CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) AS decimal(16,3)) * 0.009 
FROM sys.objects
```

The factor in use (here it's 0.009) can easily be handed in as variable...

### UPDATE

Use this if you want to start with `0`

```
SELECT TOP 10 name
             ,CAST((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name)-1) AS decimal(16,3)) * 0.009 
FROM sys.objects
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you want to multiply each ROW_NUMBER() by your increment value?

```
SELECT TOP 10
    AccountNumber,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AccountNumber) * 10 AS 'yValue'
FROM dbo.Acccounts

AccountNumber   yValue
1               10
2               20
3               30
4               40
5               50
6               60
30106           70
30107           80
30108           90
30109           100
```